# WordPress WP Query $arg for displaying current post/page

Tags: wordpress

This may sound like a really stupid question and/or there may be a really easy solution that I'm overlooking but is there a WP Query $arg for displaying the content of the current post/page? (i.e. if you are on the page http://www.example.com/?p=1, the wp query will return the content of the post/page with id=1). Please don't ask why or offer alternative solutions. It's a long story and I just wondering if its possible. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to display the page, just enter the address in the URL and you will get the content...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté He's talking about WordPress-theming not just visiting the website.

Comment: OK, that was stupid. You just don't enter any args, lol

Comment: ...and yes, it is for custom theming.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress gets the content for the current page/post by default. If you have edited the WordPress query before you can reset it with `wp_reset_query();`

After the reset you can loop through the content for the current page/post again.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: In this case, the wordpress loop is not present on the page template (single.php). There's only the WP Query that I'm trying to get the current page content from.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and add the WordPress loop? http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop